# With which package will I create, in the shortest code, two points with horizontal error bars with overlap region dashed?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, metapost

[image: That's how I want it to be.]

Pgfplots? Metapost? Tikz?

As I can't make it right now with any of them, I have to choose one of them to study. Which of them? Which has shortest code? Which has best image quality?

I don't mind if you write the code itself for me. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-4,-1.5)(6,3)
\psset{dotsize=5pt, arrowinset=0}
\dotnodes(-1,2.5){A}(1.5,1.5){B}
\pnodes(-1,0){H}(1.5,0){K}
\pnodes{A}(-2.5,2.5)(0.6,2.5)
\pnodes{B}(0.2,0)(0.2,1.5)(2.8,1.5)
\psframe[linewidth=0.3pt, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=SlateGray4!60](B0)(A1)
\ncline{|-|}{A0}{A1}
\ncline{|-|}{B1}{B2}
{\psset{linewidth=1.8pt}
\ncline{A0}{A1}
\ncline{B1}{B2}
\psaxes[yAxis=false, ticks=none, labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-4,0)(6,0)}
\psset{linestyle=dotted}
\ncline{A}{H}\ncline{B}{K}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Just for code-golf fun with Plain TeX and `\pdfliteral`; no packages required. :-)

```
\pdfliteral{q 0.8g 0.2w 38 0m 38 20l 42 20l 42 0l B
  1w 0g 0 0m 100 0l S 100 0m 95 1.5l 95 -1.5l b* 18 20m 42 20l S 38 10m 62 10l S
  4w 1J 30 20m 30 20l S 50 10m 50 10l S
  0.5w 0J 18 22m 18 18l S 42 22m 42 18l S 38 12m 38 8l S 62 12m 62 8l S
  [0.5 0.5] 0d 30 0m 30 20l S 50 0m 50 10l S Q}\bye
```

[image]

---

*De-minified version w/ comments (identical output):*

The PDF specification uses a PostScript-style language to lay out elements in a PDF. pdfTeX's `\pdfliteral` primitive can inject its argument right into the PDF file, so we can use it to draw graphics at a very low, pithy level.

The language uses postfix operators, so in general the operator is at the end of the line in this de-minified code while the arguments precede it. The full language specification is available online for free from Adobe: [PDF Reference and Adobe Extensions to the PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html).

In this code, a path starts with the `m` operator, contains various other *path-constructing* operators (here, mostly `l` for line), and ends with one or more *path-painting* operators (here, mostly `S` to stroke the path, but in a few places "fancier" operators are used for closing, stroking, filling, and combinations thereof).

```
\pdfliteral{
  q        % save current graphics state (for later restore)
  %% shaded overlapping region
  0.8g     % set fill color to 80% [g]rey
  0.2w     % set stroke [w]idth to 0.2pt
  38 0m    % [m]ove "pen" to coordinate (38,0) 
  38 20l   % [l]ine to (38,20)
  42 20l   % [l]ine to (42,20)
  42 0l    % [l]ine to (42,0)
  B        % fill and stroke the current path
  %% base line
  1w 0g    % set stroke width to 1pt and fill color to black
  0 0m     % move pen to the origin (0,0)
  100 0l   % line to (100,0)
  S        % stroke the current path
  %% arrowhead
  100 0m   % move pen to (100,0)
  95 1.5l  % line to (95,1.5)
  95 -1.5l % line to (95,-1.5)
  b*       % close, fill, and stroke the current path
  %% error bar base lines
  18 20m   % move pen to (18,20)
  42 20l   % line to (42,20)
  S        % stroke the current path
  38 10m   % move pen to (38,10)
  62 10l   % line to (62,10)
  S        % stroke the current path
  %% dots (zero-length lines w/ rounded line cap style)
  4w 1J    % set stroke width to 4pt and line cap style to 1 (rounded cap)
  30 20m   % move pen to (30,20)
  30 20l   % line to (30,20)
  S        % stroke the current path 
  50 10m   % move pen to (50,10)
  50 10l   % line to (50,10)
  S        % stroke the current path
  %% error bar ends
  0.5w 0J  % set stroke width to 0.5pt and line cap style to 0 (butt cap)
  18 22m   % move pen to (18,22)
  18 18l   % line to (18,18)
  S        % stroke the current path
  42 22m   % move pen to (42,22)
  42 18l   % line to (42,18)
  S        % stroke the current path
  38 12m   % move pen to (38,12)
  38 8l    % line to (38,8)
  S        % stroke the current path
  62 12m   % move pen to (62,12)
  62 8l    % line to (62,8)
  S        % stroke the current path
  %% dotted lines from dots to base line
  [0.5 0.5] 0d % set the dash pattern to "0.5pt on, 0.5pt off, phase 0"
  30 0m    % move pen to (30,0)
  30 20l   % line to (30,20) 
  S        % stroke the current path
  50 0m    % move pen to (50,0)
  50 10l   % line to (50,10)
  S        % stroke the current path 
  Q        % restore original graphics state
}\bye
```

Comment: This looks very cryptic, are you sure it's not a secret message to someone? :P Very nice work!

Comment: I have no idea why an answer with longer code was accepted over mine... ;-)

Comment: How did you do this?

Comment: Paul, do you mind adding a small explanation about the numbers? Like, what do they do? I don't need a very detailed explanation, just something to give me an idea. :D

Comment: @PaulGessler I didn't choose your answer because,  when I copy and paste your command into a MWE, I only get errors such as `Undefined control sequence`,  `==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!` or ` No pages of output.`, depending on the Overleaf settings, so I couldn't check if that really worked. I guess I'm not being able to configure Overleaf to use Plain Tex. I'm gonna try Unix command line soon.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro hi! Please see the instructions [here](https://www.overleaf.com/help/211-can-i-run-plain-tex-on-overleaf#.VonEAPkrKHs) if you'd like to run Plain TeX on Overleaf to test this out. :-)

Comment: @PaulGessler I tried that today, but it still didn't work. I just tried `tex example.tex` in MacBook terminal, but the message was the same: `! Undefined control sequence. l.1 \pdfliteral`. To be honest, I know nothing about `pdfliteral`. Shouldn't I install it or call it as a package or add something before it for it to be recognize?

Comment: @LeonardoCastro ah, yes, sorry, you have to use `pdftex` for this code. `\pdfliteral` is a primitive added to `pdftex`. It is not included in the original `tex` binary.

Comment: @PaulGessler With `pdftex example.tex` I could compile it, but the resulting PDF is a blank page and Acrobat Reader shows a message like "There is an error in this document. Contact the person who created it. [...]" (I'm not writing the literal message because it's in Portuguese to me.) I wonder if some characters are being copied with wrong codification when I copy-paste them. I'll try to type them all instead of copying.

Comment: @PaulGessler I just had it working by putting the `\pdfliteral{...}` command inside a `hbox` and compiling it with LuaLatex in Overleaf. If I take the `\pdfliteral{...}` out the `hbox`, it only works if I write some text before it. A lone `\pdfliteral{...}` between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` causes `Undefined control sequence.` Go figure...

Comment: Well, as the code of this answer is actually shorter, I guess I should switch the "accepted answer" tick to it. It also has more votes, so the _vox populi vox Dei_ criterion also favors this answer. Any objections? Anyway, the competing answerers both have a number of points in the _k_ order and probably don't care about this question too much. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Not sure about shortest code, but here's a plain Metapost effort showing the `ahangle` trick you can use to make error bars.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

path xx, e[], box;

xx = origin -- right scaled 60mm;

e1 = (left--right) scaled 11mm shifted (42mm,7mm);
e2 = (left--right) scaled 10mm shifted (26mm,14mm);

box = unitsquare xscaled abs xpart (point 0 of e1 - point 1 of e2) 
                 yscaled abs ypart point 1 of e2
                 shifted (xpart point 0 of e1,0);

fill box withcolor .8[red,white];
draw box withcolor .4[red,white];

drawarrow xx withpen pencircle scaled 1;

ahangle := 180; % a trick to make error bars using "drawdblarrow"
ahlength := 3;

forsuffixes $=1,2: 
   drawdblarrow e$ withpen pencircle scaled 1; 
   z$ = point 1/2 of e$;
   draw z$ -- (x$,0) dashed withdots scaled 1/3;
   fill fullcircle scaled 6 shifted z$;
endfor

endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 6):

## New version

This uses a `pic` to draw the dots with errorbars.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
 errorball/.pic={
   \draw [Bar-Bar,very thick,shorten <=-0.5\pgflinewidth,shorten >=-0.5\pgflinewidth] (-1,0) coordinate (-left) -- (1,0) coordinate (-right);
   \node[minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt,fill,circle] (-ball) at (0,0) {};
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-latex,very thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\pic (upper) at (2,2) {errorball};
\pic (lower) at (3.5,1) {errorball};

\foreach \ball in {upper,lower}
  \draw [densely dotted] (\ball-ball) -- (\ball-ball|-0,0);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[black!10,draw=black] (upper-right) rectangle (lower-left |- 0,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Old answer

One suggestion with TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-latex,very thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [Bar-Bar,very thick] (1,2) -- node[fill,circle] (a) {} +(2,0);
\draw [Bar-Bar,very thick] (2.5,1) -- node[fill,circle] (b) {} +(2,0);
\draw [densely dotted] (a) -- (a|-0,0)
                       (b) -- (b|-0,0);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[gray] (2.5,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```